# Julia - scatter plot: how do I define different colors for each class?

Tags: plot, julia, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatter plot in Julia, where I have 3 classes.
I would like to define different color for each of these classes.

I tried:

```
using(PyPlot)
pca = readdlm("pca1_2_fam.txt", header=false);
plot(pca[:,3], pca[:,4], color = pca[:,1])
```

The pca file is like:

Name1  208094 -0.00476681  0.00822032
Name1  514876 -0.00531507 -0.00721858
Name2  515043  0.00365503 -0.01794700
Name2  515066  0.00467896  0.00420396
Name3  799073  0.00811660 -0.01903420
Name3 GLTGH40  0.00380041  0.00618471

In R, I did this just using:

```
colnames(pca)=c("Breed","Animal","PCA1","PCA2")
qplot(PCA1,PCA2,data=pca,color=Breed,geom=c("point")) + theme(legend.position="none")
```

I would like to learn how to do this in Julia.

Comment: Try `using PyPlot`....?

Answer (score 5):

I've found that PyPlot is overall the best option for plotting in Julia, though there are also many other packages (Winston, Gadfly, Plotly, etc.).  PyPlot is essentially a wrapper for the Python library Matplotlib which itself roughly seeks to emulate plotting available in Matlab but from a more "pythonic" perspective.

Here is an example that should accomplish what you're seeking:

```
using PyPlot
(X1, Y1) = (rand(6), rand(6));
(X2, Y2) = (rand(6), rand(6));
(X3, Y3) = (rand(6), rand(6));

fig = figure(figsize=(10,10))
# xlabel("My X Label")  # optional x label
# ylabel("My Y Label")  # optional y label
title("Julia Plots Like a Boss")
R = scatter(X1,Y1,color="red", label = "Red Data", s = 40)
G = scatter(X2,Y2,color="blue", label = "Blue Data", s = 60)
B = scatter(X3,Y3,color="green", label = "Green Data", s = 80)
legend(loc="right")
savefig("/path/to/pca1_2_fam.pdf")  ## optional command to save results.
```

[image]

Comments:

You will need python and matplotlib installed already in order for this to work.  A decent, but by no means only way to do this, is to install Anaconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

You can get help on all of the functions used here via the regular Julia interface, e.g. `?scatter` gives you lots of options to configure your plots.

You can find the PyPlot documentation [here](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl) and a bunch of examples to follow [here](https://gist.github.com/gizmaa/7214002)  (note, there is a link for each example to show the full code either on github or via IJulia).

You can also consult the full Matplotlib documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/contents.html).  In particular, the [beginner's guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/beginner.html) and [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) will be useful to give you ideas.  You'll need to do a bit of work at times to translate these to Julia, but hopefully the other specific-to-julia resources I mentioned above will give the needed guidance for that.

**Update:**

As GersonOliveiraJunior suggested in comments, if you want to do this by first reading in the data from file, you can use something like this:

```
using DataFrames, PyPlot
pca2 = readtable("path/to/pca1_2_fam.txt", header=false, separator = ' ')
G = pca2[pca2[:,1].=="Name1",3:4]
R = pca2[pca2[:,1].=="Name2",3:4]
B = pca2[pca2[:,1].=="Name3",3:4]

fig = figure(figsize=(10,10))
title("Julia Plots Like a Boss")
scatter(G[:,1],G[:,2],color="green", label = "Green Data", s = 40)
scatter(R[:,1],R[:,2],color="red", label = "Red Data", s = 40)
scatter(B[:,1],B[:,2],color="blue", label = "Blue Data", s = 40)
legend(loc="right")
```

Comment: Thanks aireties
As a have a single file, do I need to split the file in three, considering the different categoies (NAME1, NAME2 , NAME3)? 
Actually I tried to split my file but it's not working.  
Is there something like:  
`name1 = pca[pca[,1] == "NAME1",]`  

Thank you.

Comment: **UPDATE**     
I realized that if I convert my file in a DataFrame using:  
`pca2 = convert(DataFrame, pca)`    
then, for subset the file I have used:  
`G = pca2[pca2[:,1].=="NAME1",:];`    
So, I did this for all the classes and then your code works. :)
But, if you know a better way to do this, please tell me

Comment: @GersonOliveiraJunior Yes, that works!  You can do it without the conversion if you use `readtable()` to first load your data in.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you.   Just one more question.   Do you have any tips to save this plot in good quality. My idea is use this plot in a Word document.   Thanks.

Comment: @GersonOliveiraJunior You can use `savefig()` after this.  See `?savefig()` for options and updated answer giving example above.  You can adjust quality by (a) choosing the `dpi` level in the `savefig()` function and/or (b) by adjusting the `figsize()` option in the `fig()` function.

Comment: Hi again. I'm trying to set x and y labels like: `xlabel("X")` and `ylabel("Y")` at the end of the command, but is not working.
Do you know how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: @GersonOliveiraJunior I haven't checked this explicitly, but I would think you would want those after you call the `figure()` function but before you call the `scatter()` functions.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing like this.
The code that I'm using is:
`fig = figure(figsize=(10,10))  
xlim(xmax=0.03)  
xlim(xmin=-0.04)  
ylim(ymax=0.15)  
ylim(ymin=-0.10)  
R = scatter(H[:,3],H[:,4],color="red", label="Holstein",s=30)  
G = scatter(G[:,3],G[:,4],color="blue", label="Gyr",s=30)  
B = scatter(G2[:,3],G2[:,4],color="green", label="Girolando",s=30)  
legend(loc="best")  
savefig("myplot.eps", dpi=800)` . I have added the `xlabel` and `ylabel` after `yim`.

Comment: @GersonOliveiraJunior I cannot reproduce your error.  The `xlabel()` and `ylabel()` functions work fine for me.  I updated my code example above to include them (though they're commented out so that the code itself still matches the picture).  Are you perhaps missing the line breaks or semicolons between your commands?  Maybe try exiting Julia and starting again? (perhaps something just got wonky with your current plot).

Comment: @GersonOliveiraJunior Also, if you continue having more questions / issues arise, I recommend starting a new question.  It will be easier for future users to find answers rather than them needing to scroll through lots of comments.

Answer (score 3):

If you are already familiar with `ggplot2` I would recommend you to look at `Gadfly`. It is based on the same grammar of graphics principles as `ggplot2` and you will find it's features very similar to the R package.

Your above try would also work in `Gadfly`:

```
using Gadfly

pca = readdlm("pca1_2_fam.txt", header=false);
plot(x = pca[:,3], y= pca[:,4], color = pca[:,1])
```

[image]

Don't forget to install the package first with `Pkg.add("Gadfly")`.
You can also find some tutorials here: https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl
Also check out the `DataFrames` package for easier plotting and data manipulation: https://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Is Gadfly still being maintained?

Comment: @daycaster I have no idea. I just know that's very similar to ggplot and that's why I recommended it.

Comment: Thanks niczky12         
I tried your suggestion but I just received a empty plot (no dots)      
In the bottom there was a message       
0-element Array{Any,1}       
I didn't understand because the file name is correct.       
Any idea?

Comment: @GersonOliveiraJunior If you have an empty plot with no data points, then it's safe to say that there was some error with the data read step. Have you checked whether `readdlm` created your array as expected?

Comment: @niczky12 Yes, I checked the file.  It's 1828x4 Array{Any,2}.
I also have tried to convert as a DataFrame, but still the same, no dots. :(
If I just write like: `plot(pca[:,3], pca[:,4])` works, but this is a diffenrent plot.  Thank you!